# ExtJS4 TimeField increment

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I just want to have 2 (08:00 and 13:00) values in a TimeField :

```
xtype: 'timefield',
name: 'operation[starthour]',
editable: false,
minValue: '08:00',
maxValue: '13:00',
value: '08:00',
increment: 300
```

It doesn't work at all. With this code I just have 10:00 value in the combobox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The docs say:

> The number of minutes between each time value in the list.

An increment of 300 means 5 hours.